# Installation from Image on SSD failed with exit code 141

Tags: boot, kubuntu, uefi, ssd

Since I can't boot from USB because the UEFI of my laptop is locked by password (which I don't have) I need to install kubuntu from the ssd (prepared as a bootable live image with rufus). kubuntu starts properly but fails if I try to install with exit code 141 (Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141). The ssd is mount as /cdrom. Any ideas how to install it on the boot ssd?

Comment: It looks like your computer is owned by your office/school and they don't want you to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: If your computer is (or was) owned by a school, I do not recommend trying to install KUbuntu on it. This could get you in lots of trouble, and the school will not be happy. If it was owned by a school, and you cannot access the BIOS, either contact the school to ask for the password or get a new device.

Comment: In a nutshell, even if you manage to install you can't use it without changing the boot order in UEFI. So, obviously, you need to obtain the password. Again, if the computer isn't owned by you then you shouldn't be installing OSes.

Comment: Remove and then replace the motherboard battery, this should wipe the BIOS password.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is (or was) owned by a school, I do not recommend trying to install KUbuntu on it. This could get you in lots of trouble, and the school will not be happy. If it was owned by a school, and you cannot access the BIOS, either contact the school to ask for the password or get a new device.

Also, since Ubuntu is set to install on the SSD of your device, it will not install if the image is on the SSD, and cannot erase it because it needs the data on the image to install. Since your BIOS is locked, there is no way to be able to install KUbuntu unless you can create and resize partitions on your SSD from the Ubiquity installer. I would try the 'running KUbuntu without installing' option and partition your drive from the KUbuntu disk utility.

Comment: It's a laptop bought on ebay. Thanks for the comment. I will try to return it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is your computer ( not from your work or school ) and you are unable to obtain the password, and you have a lot of technical skills, clear the CMOS ( open the laptop ). Find out the layout of the motherboard. You really have to know what you are doing to perform this operation.